# get ROW NUMBER of random records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For a simple SQL like,

```
SELECT top 3 MyId FROM MyTable ORDER BY NEWID()
```

how to add row numbers to them so that the row numbers become 1,2, and 3?

**UPDATE:**

I thought I can simplify my question as above, but it turns out to be more complicated. So here is a fuller version -- I need to give three random picks (from `MyTable`) for each person, with pick/row number of 1, 2, and 3, and there is no logical joining between person and picks.

```
SELECT * FROM Person
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT top 3 MyId FROM MyTable ORDER BY NEWID()
) D ON 1=1
```

The problem with above SQL are,

- Obviously, pick/row number of 1, 2, and 3 should be added
- and what is not obvious is that, the above SQL will give each person the *same* picks, whereas I need to give different person different picks

Here is a working SQL to test it out:

```
SELECT TOP 15 database_id, create_date, cs.name FROM sys.databases
CROSS apply ( 
  SELECT top 3 Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNo,*
  FROM (SELECT top 3 name from sys.all_views ORDER BY NEWID()) T
  ) cs
```

So, Please help.

**NOTE:** This is *NOT* about MySQL byt T-SQL as their syntax are *different*, Thus the solution is *different* as well.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (select null))`

Comment: @Prdp, thx but row numbers are not 1,2, and 3 but something random.

Comment: Since you are selecting rows at random (`TOP 3` from `ORDER BY NEWID()`), what order do you expect in the sample results you won't share with us?

Comment: @HABO, as long as row numbers are 1,2, and 3, I'm fine, as you've noticed, I'm selecting rows at random anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `Row_number` to outer query. Try this

```
SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),*
FROM   (SELECT TOP 3 MyId
        FROM   MyTable
        ORDER  BY Newid()) a
```

Logically `TOP` keyword is processed after `Select`. After Row Number is generated random 3 records will be pulled.  So you should not generate Row Number in original query

**Update**

It can be achieved through `CROSS APPLY`. Replace the column names inside cross apply `where` clause with valid column name from `Person` table

```
SELECT *
FROM   Person p
       CROSS apply (SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn,*
                    FROM   (SELECT TOP 3 MyId
                            FROM   MyTable
                            WHERE  p.some_col = p.some_col -- Replace it with some column from person table
                            ORDER  BY Newid())a) cs
```

Comment: It turns out that I DO need to generate Row Number in original query, once I plugged it into the bigger query that I'm writing. So could you **add** the solution to it please?

Comment: @xpt - sorry, I didnt get it can you explain it with example or in detail

Comment: thx. I found it is still giving each person the same picks. OP updated with a working SQL for you to try at your side. Thx.

Comment: Actually, `TOP` is processed after `ORDER BY`, which is processed after `SELECT`. Using the newer syntax, you would write `ORDER BY … OFFSET … FETCH …`. Also SQL Server is quirky it allowing `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`, which gives unreliable results.