# How to "pick" random records with T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is a simple question that is actually hard to answer, because the "picking" has a special meaning.

I need to give three random picks for each person (and give pick/row number of 1, 2, and 3). What makes it hard is that the persons and picks are from different tables and there is no logical joining between the person and picks.

The [closest I can get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022467/) is:

```
SELECT TOP 15 database_id, create_date, RowNo, cs.name FROM sys.databases
CROSS apply ( 
  SELECT top 3 Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNo,*
  FROM (SELECT top 3 name from sys.all_views ORDER BY NEWID()) T
  ) cs
```

I know the above is not person and picks, but it a working SQL that anyone can test it out without creating person and picks tables first. And,

It illustrates the problem I'm facing --

the above SQL will give each person the same picks, whereas I need to give different person different picks.

How to do that? Thx.

Comment: upvoted for  *working SQL that anyone can test*

Comment: @Prdp I agree.  I wish more recognized the value of a simple copy/paste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a correlated condition inside the `CROSS APPLY` will solve your problem

```
SELECT TOP 15 database_id,
              create_date,
              RowNo,
              cs.NAME
FROM   sys.databases d
       CROSS apply (SELECT TOP 3 Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNo, *
                    FROM   (SELECT TOP 3 NAME
                            FROM   sys.all_views v
                            WHERE  d.NAME = d.NAME --Here
                            ORDER  BY Newid()) T) cs
```

Check the `alias` name in `Where` clause both LHS and RHS are from same `table` and same `column` it is just to execute the sub-query for each row in `databases` table

Comment: Thanks a lot @Prdp, as always. Will test it tomorrow and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your own answer slightly will do the job. Check this.

```
SELECT TOP 15 database_id, create_date, RowNo, cs.name FROM sys.databases
CROSS apply ( 
  SELECT top 3 Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RowNo,*
  FROM (SELECT top 3 name from sys.all_views ORDER BY NEWID()) T
  ) cs
```

The only change that I have done is to replace the `NULL` with `NEWID()`.

Comment: No, actually Chamika, `sys.databases` and `sys.all_views` are kind of not ordinary tables -- the SQL works for them but don't work for my real case. You can try some real tables yourself. I know, the inconsistency drives me crazy as well.

Answer (score -5):

Random function is available in Sql language could use it to randomly pick a record id in a range of record ids found in the source table.

In a newer sql version I think this may work but I can't test it currently.  Older sql version will not support the by rand() command.  Try this let me know if it works.  Later this week I can get you something that will work on sql 2000 and up.  I had to do this years ago.  Let me know if this works on your Sql 2008.

select top 3 from table_name order by rand()

Comment: Care to share an example? It has to be able to run under MS T-SQL BTW.

Comment: I don't have access to a sql server right now will try to in the next couple days.  What Sql server version are you on, it may alter my response?

Comment: Mine is 2012CU3. Thanks for trying. If you can provide an SQL, I can try myself. If it works, it actually would be more helpful to me, as for the row number of 1, 2, and 3, I was planning to use them to pivot into final format, of fields `person, pick1, pick2, pick3` in one row

Comment: Let me know if this works.  If it does I can modify it so you get a single row instead of three records....

Comment: No, Sir, in T-SQL random order is done by `ORDER BY NEWID()` as I shown in my OP, and in answers as well.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql

Just feed the Rand function with the range of your identity values in your table.

Comment: Have you try it before posting? Gee.