# How to join 2 tables without common key and randomly generate rows of second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, outer-apply

I have 2 tables.. [Users] and [Questions]

Users Table has..

```
UserId Name
--     ----
1      Bob
2      Ang
3      Bill
```

And Question Table has..

```
QuestId Description CategoryId
------- ----------  --------
0       Question0   1
1       Question1   1
2       Question2   1
3       Question3   1
4       Question4   1
5       Question5   1
6       Question6   1
7       Question7   1
8       Question9   1
9       Question9   1
10      Question10  2
```

Now, what I want is, select 5 random questions for each [User].

I've tried this query..

```
SELECT [User].UserId,Name, QuestId, Description from Users OUTER APPLY 
(SELECT TOP 5 QuestId, Description FROM Question WHERE CategoryId=1 ORDER BY NEWID(), 
Question.Id) RandomQuestions
```

And it's resulting like to something like this..

```
UserId Name QuestId Description
------ ---- ------- -----------
1      Bob  2       Question2
1      Bob  3       Question3
1      Bob  6       Question6
1      Bob  8       Question8
1      Bob  9       Question9

2      Ang  2       Question2
2      Ang  3       Question3
2      Ang  6       Question6
2      Ang  8       Question8
2      Ang  9       Question9

3      Bill 2       Question2
3      Bill 3       Question3
3      Bill 6       Question6
3      Bill 8       Question8
3      Bill 9       Question9
```

The problem with this, the QuestId is being generated randomly but if you notice, each Users has the same generated random questions. I want each Users to have different set of random Questions.

Comment: May be this one help to you : [Link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580639/how-to-randomly-select-rows-in-sql

Comment: @Shusang I have been in there, that link helped me but it was just a simple randomized rows, no joining and other logic.

Comment: This sounds like a job for `cross apply`. Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030295/how-to-pick-random-records-with-t-sql

Comment: Your existing query should returns a random sets of questions per user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this one:

```
SELECT UserId,Name,QuestId, Description
FROM   Users  a
CROSS apply (
SELECT TOP 5 Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNo, *
            FROM   (SELECT TOP 5 QuestId, Description
                    FROM   Question  b
                    WHERE  a.UserId = a.UserId 
                    ORDER  BY Newid()) S
) cs
```

Comment: Hi @Shusang, your answer works perfectly. But I'm intrigued by it. Why is it whenever I remove the "a.UserId = a.UserId", the result is, each Users are having the same generated question again. Could you please explain why is that happening?
Also, what is the purpose of Row_number()? Because when I remove it, nothing changes. Same result.

Comment: Hi @Jhe, we have give reference of 'Users a' record to cross apply join with 'Quetion b'  so all user based get top 5 result display. and no need to use Row_number() if you have not need. Only for use display user wise question number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to random `QuestionID` like this

```
WHERE QuestId = (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 10)) + 1
```